# PDFBox How to set PDF document security printing to low resolution

Tags: java, chromium, pdfbox

TL;DR;
How can PDFBox be used to generate a PDF with "low resolution" under Document Seurity > Details > Printing?

I'm trying to create a PDF using Java and I'm trying to set the value of the printing property, under document security, to low resolution.

I'm trying to do this because the application I'm working on, stumbled across this chrome bug
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1307219 and I'm trying to understand which part of it is setting such value (and, of course, the part that manages PDFs is an old spaghetti code set of classes)

As far as I understood from [PDFBox docs](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/encryption/AccessPermission.html#setCanPrintDegraded(boolean)) my goal should be achievable by playing with the AccessPermission class and setCanPrintDegraded()

I've created a simple class that generates PDFs using PDFBox, however, no matter what I try, every single PDF I create comes out with "high resolution". Am I using the correct flag?
Thanks!

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {

        PDPage myPage = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(myPage);


        try (PDPageContentStream cont = new PDPageContentStream(doc, myPage)) {

            cont.beginText();

            cont.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
            cont.setLeading(14.5f);

            cont.newLineAtOffset(25, 700);
            String line1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, " +
                    "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. " ;
            cont.showText(line1);
            cont.newLine();
            String line2 = "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. " +
                    "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. " ;
            cont.showText(line2);
            cont.newLine();
            String line3 = "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." ;
            cont.showText(line3);
            cont.newLine();

            cont.endText();
        }

        AccessPermission permission = new AccessPermission();
        permission.setCanPrintDegraded(true);
        permission.setReadOnly();
        StandardProtectionPolicy policy = new StandardProtectionPolicy("", "", permission);
        doc.protect(policy);
        doc.save("src/main/resources/setCanPrintDegradedTrueANDreadOnly.pdf");

    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting AES encryption and set the PDF version to at least 1.5. (Because the security handler revision must be at least 3. 3 isn't used, so you need 4, which is in PDF 1.5). See Table 21 and 22 of the PDF 32000 specification; 22 for what flags to set. And yes this is a real pain, I'm not even sure I'm correct here. You also need to disable print. (bit 3)

Comment: first of all, thank you! 
>Try setting AES encryption and set the PDF version to at least 1.5

I revised my code adding doc.setVersion(1.5F);
and 

StandardProtectionPolicy policy = new StandardProtectionPolicy("test", "", permission);
policy.setEncryptionKeyLength(keyLength);
doc.protect(policy);

These 2 changes should fix the 1st point (keyLenght = 128)

>  See Table 21 and 22 of the PDF 32000 specification; 22 for what flags to set.

I found the tables in the ISO, now I need to understand them :) I'll keep you posted.

Comment: > You also need to disable print. (bit 3)

one point on this, if I disable print with  permission.setCanPrint(false) the value under Document Seurity > Details > Printing becomes 'none'.

Comment: Another thing to try: `setCanPrint(true)` and `setCanPrintDegraded(false);` (this is what table 22 tells: "When this bit is clear (and bit 3 is set), printing is limited to a low-level representation of the appearance, possibly of degraded quality."). If this works, then our javadoc is wrong.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr you're great! it works!!!!!!!! I'll answer my question to make the resolution more visible but here's what I've changed (following your suggestions) to make it work.

1) I've set the following permissions:
AccessPermission permission = new AccessPermission();
permission.setCanPrint(true);
permission.setCanPrintDegraded(false);
2) I've encrypted the pdf 
Int keyLeght = 128
StandardProtectionPolicy policy = new StandardProtectionPolicy("test", "", permission);            policy.setEncryptionKeyLength(keyLength);


No need to set the doc version.
THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: Name and javadoc improved in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to @TilmanHausherr (see the comments to the question).

In order to get 'low quality' under Document Security > Details > Printing

[image]

I had to apply the following changes to the original code:

1. I've set the following permissions:

   AccessPermission permission = new AccessPermission(); permission.setCanPrint(true); permission.setCanPrintDegraded(false);
2. I've encrypted the pdf

   Int keyLeght = 128 StandardProtectionPolicy policy = new StandardProtectionPolicy("test", "", permission); policy.setEncryptionKeyLength(keyLength);

Here's the updated code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.AccessPermission;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardProtectionPolicy;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;

public class JavaPdfBoxWriteText {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {
            int keyLength = 128;
            PDPage myPage = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage(myPage);


            try (PDPageContentStream cont = new PDPageContentStream(doc, myPage)) {

                cont.beginText();

                cont.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
                cont.setLeading(14.5f);

                cont.newLineAtOffset(25, 700);
                String line1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, " +
                        "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. " ;
                cont.showText(line1);
                cont.newLine();
                String line2 = "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. " +
                        "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. " ;
                cont.showText(line2);
                cont.newLine();
                String line3 = "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." ;
                cont.showText(line3);
                cont.newLine();

                cont.endText();
            }
            AccessPermission permission = new AccessPermission();
            permission.setCanPrint(true);
            permission.setCanPrintDegraded(false);

            StandardProtectionPolicy policy = new StandardProtectionPolicy("test", "", permission);
            policy.setEncryptionKeyLength(keyLength);
            doc.protect(policy);
            doc.save("src/main/resources/testPDF.pdf");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: >anyway bug is now fixed so no need for lo-quality

true, the bug is now fixed, still, the fix is not yet out (it will with chrome v-101) 

Anyway, my aim was to find the combination of flags to be set to print in low resolution as I've noticed a weird behavior of the application I'm working on and I need to investigate that.